# Table data echoes above table rather than inside

Tags: php

I need the table to be populated with the database information. However, the echoed HTML is not being inserted into the DOM where I expect it to go (inside the table). Instead it lands above the table. Strangely, it is below the `<h1>` tag, so I know the echo is not happening before content is loaded into the page.

[image: photo demonstrating the case]

Inspecting the dynamic content reveals that none of my tags are included, and all the data dumped as a single string.

What am I doing wrong, or is there a different approach to ensure the table data is actually in the table?

**HTML**

```
    <h1>Contact Us Form Data</h1>

    <table>

        <thead>
            <tr>
                 <th>First Name</th>
                 <th>Last Name</th>
                 <th>Email</th>
                 <th>Interest</th>
                 <th>Employment</th>
                 <th>City</th>
                 <th>State</th>
                 <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php echo display_records() ?>
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

**PHP**

```
function fetch_records() {
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuname = "user";
    $dbpass = "pass";
    $dbname = "db_dev";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuname, $dbpass, $dbname);

    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM `contact_us_form`
    ";

    return mysqli_query($conn, $query);
}

function record_to_html( $record ) {
    $html = "<td>" .
        "<tr>" . $record->first_name . "</tr>" .
        "<tr>" . $record->last_name . "</tr>" .
        "<tr>" . $record->email . "</tr>" .
        "<tr>" . $record->interest . "</tr>" .
        "<tr>" . $record->employment . "</tr>" .
        "<tr>" . $record->city . "</tr>" .
        "<tr>" . $record->state . "</tr>" .
        "<tr>" . $record->date . "</tr>" .
    "</td>";

    return $html;
}

function display_records() {
    $result = fetch_records();

    $html = "";

    while ( $row = $result->fetch_object() ) {
        $html .= record_to_html( $row );
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: You're mixing TDs and TRs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this code:

```
$html = "<td>" .
    "<tr>" . $record->first_name . "</tr>" .
    "<tr>" . $record->last_name . "</tr>" .
    "<tr>" . $record->email . "</tr>" .
    "<tr>" . $record->interest . "</tr>" .
    "<tr>" . $record->employment . "</tr>" .
    "<tr>" . $record->city . "</tr>" .
    "<tr>" . $record->state . "</tr>" .
    "<tr>" . $record->date . "</tr>" .
"</td>";
```

`<tr>` and `</tr>` should be `<td>` and `</td>`, and vice versa.